# Querying a MySQL databse from JavaScript, with a WHERE clause

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a database, inside it I have, Name and Address my node.js application queries the name row with what ever was entered into the text prompt. 
[image]

I am aware that they are the wrong way round, going to flip them round now, if the user searched for Ubuntu, I would like the database to return http://google.com, new to JavaScript and any help would be greatly appreciated!

My current code.

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
 host     : 'localhost',
 user     : 'root', //just using root for my personal testing.
 password : 'root',
 database : 'Sonic'
 });

 connection.connect();

  //make the query string
  var sql01    = 'SELECT Name FROM SonicURl WHERE name = ' +      
  connection.escape(input);
 //Attempt to query the database over the connection.
  connection.query( sql01, function(err, rows) {
if (err){
  console.log('Error');
 } else if (rows[0] !== undefined && input == rows[0].name) {

 console.log(rows[0].address);
}
 connection.release();
 });
  //shut down code
   process.on( 'SIGINT', function() {
   console.log( "\nGoodbye!");
   // Other stuff that needs ending and what not.
   process.exit( );
   });
```

Comment: the standard WHERE mysql query.

Comment: Recommended close reason: Unclear, or Typo, based on comment under an accepted answer.

Comment: I don't know if you bothered to check, but there is a accepted answer, its pretty clear what I am asking, user2267175 appears to have got the idea of what I'm asking? I'm confused... and yes, autocorrect decided to sabotage my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned node.js, i'll assume you're doing this serverside.
with the node.js mysql module.

```
//After mysql connection have been made, and it is called connection.

//make the query string
var sql01    = 'SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE name = ' + connection.escape(yourTextInput);

//Attempt to query the database over the connection.
connection.query( sql01, function(err, rows) {
  if (err){
      console.log('Error');
  } else if (rows[0] !== undefined && yourTextInput == rows[0].name) {

    //Do something with address, (rows[0].address).
 }
  connection.release();
});
```

**Update:**

Personally i use pool connections, but give this a go.
it's the standard/recommended way to handle normal connections.

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'root',
 database  : 'sonic'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
if (err) {
  console.log('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
  return;
}
console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);


//make the query string
var sql01    = 'SELECT * FROM SonicURl WHERE name = ' +connection.escape(input);

//Attempt to query the database over the connection.
connection.query( sql01, function(err, rows) {
if (err){
  console.log('Error, no result');
} else if (rows[0] !== undefined && input == rows[0].name) {
 console.log(rows[0].address);
}
 connection.end();
console.log('Connection should be terminated and this should be empty or undefined:' + connection.threadId);
});  
});
```

If you want to keep your current structure, and not check if there are any errors connecting to the DB(as the above example does), you can also, simply do this:

```
connection.connect();

//make the query string
var sql01    = 'SELECT * FROM SonicURl WHERE name = ' + connection.escape(input);
//Attempt to query the database over the connection.
connection.query( sql01, function(err, rows) {
if (err){
 console.log('Error');
} else if (rows[0] !== undefined && input == rows[0].name) {

 console.log(rows[0].address);
}
});
connection.end();
```

Note: you shouldn't be selecting name, since that will only return the name value where name = input..

Comment: Hmm, connection.release is apparently not a function, am I missing something here?

Comment: Could you post your connection code please?

Comment: I will edit the question with the code.

Comment: My bad, connection.release is only used for pool connections.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple things to take care of here.

1. Your comparison should be all lowercase, in both the input and the table' data. (i.e. usage of toLower() in Javascript and TOLOWER() in MySQL)
2. You do not enclose parameter in quotes; it should be 
   var sql01    = 'SELECT Name FROM SonicURl WHERE name = ' + '\'' + connection.escape(input) + '\'';
   since it's a string value.
3. Perhaps the last thing is the name of the column - Name - must be also camel-cased in the query as well - although this is not a strict requirement, I believe.

Comment: Using nodejs-Mysql module,
var sql    = 'SELECT * FROM x WHERE y = ' + connection.escape(input);

is all you need to do, regarding escaping.